# Comparing Strings in IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython

I am trying to compare two strings while searching for WSUS groups to update.  However, my comparison is failing even though they appear to be the same visually, and are of the same type.  Since this is IronPython, I don't have a debugger available in Komodo (anyone know of one for IP?)

Anyway, can someone spot what I am doing wrong?

```
 #----------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Search for a matching patch group, and approve them.
 #----------------------------------------------------------------------
 def WSUSApprove(apprvGrpName):
     clr.AddReference('Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration')
     import Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration

     wsus = Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy.GetUpdateServer('wsus01',False,8530)

     parentGroupCollection = wsus.GetComputerTargetGroups()
     for computerTarget in parentGroupCollection:
         if computerTarget.Name.ToString() == 'Servers':
             parent = computerTarget
             childGroupCollection = parent.GetChildTargetGroups()
             for computerTarget in childGroupCollection:
                 print type(computerTarget.Name.ToString())
                 print type(apprvGrpName)
                 if apprvGrpName == computerTarget.Name.ToString():
                     print 'success', computerTarget.Name.ToString()
                 else:
                     print 'a', computerTarget.Name.ToString()
                     print 'b', apprvGrpName

#--output that should be equal--#

 <type 'str'>
 <type 'str'>
 a 3 Tuesday
 b 3 Tuesday
```

Comment: It shows a '\n on one of them!!  Thanks for your help.  Duh.

Comment: I'll move that to an answer. Please remember to accept answers to your questions (you didn't to your first two).

Answer (score 1):

On Python 2.x, Use [`repr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr) to see visually if two strings are the same. `print` basically calls `str`, so you can't see unprintable characters and it's hard to see differences in whitespace.

So, do:

```
print repr(computerTarget.Name.ToString())
print repr(apprvGrpName)
```

to find out why they aren't equivalent.

See John Manchin's comment for what to use on Python 3.x, where `repr()` doesn't escape unicode characters.

Comment: With Python 3.x, use `ascii()`. The Python 3.x `repr()` doesn't represent non-ASCII characters with escape sequences, leaving considerable scope for ambiguity.

Comment: doesn't matter if it's a Python 1.x question, don't say "always".

Answer (score 0):

Most likely one of your strings has a trailing whitespace character such as a newline, carriage return or space.

Comment: Yes, he knows this, because he used `repr` after I advised him to. See the comments on the question.